# Mapping a file in c programming

Tags: c, file-io

I read somewhere that when a regular c/c++ application needs to access a file, it is common to place the file's content in process memory and read or modify it using memory operations. This is known as memory mapping or just mapping the file.

Does that mean I need to copy the data in an (on-chip)  buffer, and modify the content as needed, and then write it back in the file? Are there specific functions to achieve this?

Can someone points me to a link that describes this in detail? The problem is the word memory mapping is too broad and I am unable find the exact information.

I am working on windows-7, visual studio 2010

Comment: Search on `mmap example code` or similar.

Comment: is there a specific platform you had in mind ?

Answer (score 0):

Copying data from the file will not be needed. Memory mapping a file means, that the function you use to "open" a file gets you a buffer with that file's contents. This buffer is not RAM memory with file's contents copied, but it's a virtual memory whose access directly maps to a file on disk. I don't know how does it work in windows, but that's what mmap() call does in linux. When you modify that buffer and close the file, the contents on the disk are automatically updated.

Comment: If the buffer is not in RAM, how does this mapping improves performance ? Disk are much slower than RAM.. am I right?

Comment: You're right. I've never investigated performance of mmapped files, I know that people use this feature for random-access mostly (instead of fseek, fread you just mmap the open fd, and then have a buffer which you can index). But there are probably advanced mechanisms in each kernel to improve all (mmapped and not mmapped) file accesses, like caching contents in RAM - I bet that in linux, mmapped file is not loaded to RAM, but when you access the buffer causing page faults, the needed parts of the file are cached and then the access to that memory is not a disk access any more ;)

Comment: The buffer IS in RAM, but only the parts of the file that you actually access. The virtual memory system loads those pages into memory on demand, rather than reading the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't mean that. What you describe would be bad practice. **Very bad practice.** Memory mapping instead means that the OS creates a special pointer of which it knows about that it corresponds to a file, then whenever that pointer is accessed as an array, the OS, instead of writing to the memory (or maybe actually writing to memory also), it modifies the contents of the file on the disk, in-place. If your system is POSIX-comformant, you can use the `mmap()` function to map a file to a memory region/pointer:

```
int fd = open("/path/to/file.ext", O_RDWR);
struct stat st;
fstat(fd, &st);
uint8_t *byte_ptr = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

// read a byte from the file
uint8_t byte = byte_ptr[12];
// increment it
byte++;
// and write it back
byte_ptr[12] = byte;

close(fd);
```