# Is this going to copy all the data in my binary files?

Tags: c++

I have a huge array of string stored as binary file.

```
std::string strArr[1000];
std::ifstream file("strFile.bin",std::ios:: binary);
file.read((char*)&strArr,sizeof(strArr));
std::cout<<strArr[500];
```

Will that code copy all the data from the binary file? If so, how can I make it not copy so if I output a string it will just get it directly from file. Kinda pointer thing. I really appreciate someone will help, thanks!

Comment: Pointing to file content isn't impossible. But you still have to parse the entire file. What you're doing is already the best way.

Comment: First you should get the size of the binary file. Then `malloc` or `new` a block of buffer enough to contain all the data. At last read the file into the buffer.

Comment: read/writing data that way from/to a file only works with trivial copy-able and POD types.  And even then you could run into various problems.

Comment: You can't store `std::string`s like that at all. You need some serialization.

Comment: I/O of objects (or arrays) of non-trivial type using a binary I/O (`std::ifstream::read()` to read or `std::ifstream::write()` to write) gives undefined behaviour.   `std::string` is a non-trivial type.  You need some form of serialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not reading the entire binary file. It is creating a 1000 strings and overwriting `std::string` instance memories. If you want to read the entire binary file, you can do this:

```cpp
std::ifstream file("file.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
assert(file.is_open());
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

This will read the entire binary file and it will copy it to memory. If you don't want to explicitly copy, you can use file memory mapping on Linux (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757435/mapping-a-file-in-c-programming)).

If you are looking to serialize and deserialize 1000 `std::string`s, then its a different story. You can use a serialization library like `Cereal`.

Comment: Yeah but the string arr(1000,0); does not work on mine. Only the string arr[1000]